# GIT: Opening Commits and different repositories

Tags: git

I just started reading and studying GIT yesterday, and I already installed it in my local, made a repository, done stagings and commits, but still im not not appreciating its use much yet --obviously im a noob in GIT-- so here are some questions that are bothering me.

*Question 1:*
Ok, I can make a file in my repository and make 1 or more commits to it right? meaning I can have one file with different versions of commits, but how can I open those commits in a text editor? or am i just missing some idea here?

*Question 2:*
Ok, I can make 1 or more different repositories in different directories in my local, but I want it to put in my htdocs, so meaning I have to make a repo in my htdocs and put there all my files, then how can I test if my codes are running before commmiting it, do I have to type localhost/.git/ in my browser?

Im very sorry for my stupid questions, Im still a college student and this is my first time with VCS.

Thanks in advance Masters. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

- Q1: You can enter `git log` to get a log of all your commits. You can then enter `git checkout <version#>` to revert your working directory to a previous version of a file, where `<version#>` is one of the big long hex numbers at the front of each log entry. You usually only need to supply the first few digits, and git will tell you if it's ambiguous.
- Q2: Just as for Q1, you can use `git checkout ...` to place different versions of your code into the working directory, which will change the contents at the same `htdocs` path.

  In practice, this means that you need at least two web servers, usually referred to as dev (development) and prod (production). You can freely `git checkout ...` different versions on dev, which only you access, but prod should go through a more rigorous deployment. The simplest of these (and not particularly robust) is to copy the files into prod from a known good working directory. Also, there are numerous [online resources](http://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=git+deployment) that suggest workflows for using git itself to do prod deployments.

Comment: Hello MaxtrixFrog, I now got it running for my 1st question, still having a hard time figuring out my problem for my Q2, thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I understand your question: if you want to have two different versions of a file at once, you can branch your repository and work on the two versions separately, until you want to merge all the changes from the two versions back together.

Generally with Git, you shouldn't be afraid of committing something that breaks the code; reverting is easy, all your history is there. That's one of the things that makes VCSs so useful.

However, Git has a "hook" feature which means you can build a code test right into your commit process. So, for example, suppose you are working on a website. You could set it up so every time you try to commit, a web browser pops up so you can look at how it changed. If you approve of the results, you continue with the commit. Heck, because these Git hooks can easily invoke other programs, you could even have it automatically take a screenshot of the browser using a command line screenshot utility, and compare it to a known good screenshot using some file diff tool, to make sure it still renders the same. If you take the time to set it up, it will do this for you every commit. (This was just a random example.)

For some basic starter info on using Git's hook feature, look here:
http://progit.org/book/ch7-3.html

I hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at the reference you gave me, thank you very much.